# Text fade in, up and fadeout at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Apologies if this seems simple however I cannot seem to get this to work.

I would like to have a div and within that div have text fade in, slide up and fade out all in one motion. So far I can get the text to fade in and slide up in one motion, however, the text pauses before doing the slide fade out animation.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function(){
$('#theDIV').css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'}).animate({'opacity':'1','top':'-=50px'}, 1500);
    $('#theDIV').css({'display':'block','opacity':'1'}).animate({'opacity':'0','top':'-=50px'}, 1500);
    });
 });
```

---

```
 #theDIV{display:none; position:relative;}
```

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="theDIV">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function(){
$('#theDIV').css({'display':'none','top':'50px'});
 $('#theDIV').css({'display':'block','opacity':'0'}).animate({'opacity':'1','top':'-=50px'}, 1500);
setTimeout(function(){  $('#theDIV').css({'opacity':'1'}).animate({'opacity':'0','top':'-=50px'}, 1500); }, 1500);
    });
 });
```

```css
#theDIV{display:none; position:relative;margin:30px 150px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="theDIV">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use transform instead top style:

```
    $('#theDIV').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':'0'}).animate({'opacity':'1','transform':'translateY(-50px)'}, 1500);
    $('#theDIV').css({'display':'block', 'opacity':'1'}).animate({'opacity':'0','transform':'translateY(-50px)'}, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers you receive seems working well excepted that they use Javascript to run the animation (and the `top` attributes) which both are  bad practices for micro-interaction like yours.

I link you a [very good articles](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/animations/css-vs-javascript) of Googles about animations using Javascript vs CSS.
And a second one [Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) by Paul Irish.

Here an example using only a `toggle class` & `Keyframes` to run your animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function(){
    $('.show-up-and-fade').toggleClass('animate');
  });
});
```

```css
.show-up-and-fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.show-up-and-fade.animate {
  animation: show-up-and-fade 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes show-up-and-fade {
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Start Animation</button>

<div class="show-up-and-fade">animated text</div>
```

---

Hope it will help you !